# How to store a user's cart in Django (e-commerce)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, session-cookies

Please take a look and tell me if I'm wrong / if it is a bad method and why.

I need:

1. Anonymous user can add products to the cart.
2. Anonymous user can access his cart with the same computer even after he closes the browser.
3. Registered user can do the same + if he logs in with the other computer, he still can access his cart, made before.

My thoughts:

Registered user's model has `products_in_the_cart` field.

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import User

class MyUser(User):
    products_in_the_cart = models.Charfield(max_length=200)
```

Products, which were added to the cart, stores in cookies. If the user is authenticated, it also stores in User model.

views.py

```
def add_product_to_the_cart(request, product_id):  
    ...      
    request.COOKIES['products_in_the_cart'].append(product_id)
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        request.user.products_in_the_cart = json.dumps(request.COOKIES['products_in_the_cart'])
    return render(request, ... )
```

Finally, if the user logging in, his current `COOKIES['products_in_the_cart']`, if exists, overrides model's data. If not exists, his model's data writes down in COOKIES.

views.py

```
def user_login(request):
    ...
    login(request, user)
    if request.COOKIES.get('products_in_the_cart', False):
        user.products_in_the_cart = json.dumps(request.COOKIES['products_in_the_cart'])
    elif user.products_in_the_cart:
        request.COOKIES['products_in_the_cart'] = json.loads(user.products_in_the_cart)
    ...
```

Comment: Don't use cookies like that. Use the session framework, which stores the data in the database and a key in the cookie.